# Can we specify UIColor value in CABasicAnimation?

Tags: xcode, swift, uicolor, cabasicanimation, scnnode

I want to add a glowing animation for a 3D ball

```
let ball = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 20))

let highlightAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
highlightAnimation.toValue = UIColor.yellowColor()
highlightAnimation.fromValue = UIColor(hue: 0.01, saturation: 1,
                               brightness: 0.6, alpha: 1) //supposed to be dark red
//other unimportant codes for initialization

ball.geometry!.firstMaterial!.emission.addAnimation(highlightAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

what happen is, when I run the program, the color changes from bright red (equivalent to `UIColor.redColor`) to bright yellow instead of the color I want. Apparently the property only accepts the color from default `UIColor` property. Is there any way to customize the color?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use "backgroundColor" keyPath to animate color.

Comment: Have you tried setting the color of the material to your starting dark red before adding the animation?

Comment: @generatorOfOne it doesnt work. The compiler throws this instead: [SCNKit ERROR] backgroundColor is not an animatable path. Btw can u explain me what keypath is? I cant seem to find it online

Comment: @GaryMakin yes I already set it. In fact, I set the geometry by using custom geometry function where I set the diffuse property to a specific color